# Conditional type that narrows a union

Tags: typescript

I'm sorry for the vague title, but my question here comes from not really understanding what TS is doing in this situation so I wasn't sure what to call it.  Basically, the question is--why does this code fail:

```
type Broken<T extends string | number> = T extends string ? T : null

let foo:Broken<string>
let value: string 
foo = value

let value2: string | number
// this error makes sense to me: value2 could be a number
foo = value2
if(typeof value2 === "string")
{
    // and it makes sense to me this works, because now we know they are both strings
    foo = value2
}

function testBroken<T extends string | number>(value: T ){
    let bar: Broken<T>
    // i guess i expect this error, but i'm not sure i understand why TS says the error
    // is that "string" is not assignable to Broken<T>
    bar = value
    if(typeof value === "string"){
        // Why is this an error? if "bar" is narrowed to string don't we know that Broken<T>
        // is also "string"?
        bar = value
    }
}
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgTgewNYQHYB4AqUIA9hoAmAzlMcHAJaoDmUAPlKgK4C2ARhHAHxQC8UbHgKoSZCtToB+QVABcTZgBslAKFVKIwKADMECOfGRp05KrW4atUAG4BDJcwgKzkqKr0J+th0-Wbte0cIACYXCVoGRQ4uVQB6OKhgAAtKUi5EOChWOxRSYjQCpK9WZx9gkKgAYwRlQihOKDtozjgPfW8gpxDVSh0AClBIBB1y7v4+AQAiV1opgEpVAG9VKDWoBKbRKEptHLyyQuhgEuPU0gB3BDgkYgAaBogqu2Yi1AQLqAvoJHfPlIgICacGg7AQKXE5hoxFW608nV8oVUAF91DpmKgqsBKAhUEkIOQjCgMEJ8ER8hE6IwWDEeP0umVsPMVusoAEGnY4AoiSZMJZWZtKFAaE5iKQhXhIFikuccHBMg92MxtJQAOSsJjgsjMEE7KAYwhcch2bYXZJAzAAZTIdhApABcsysLWgvtyTs2hmlKmO1I720djFlBoqDs7E0xVgiGJWH563YnIRwWdOwGQwgIzG0Em01mNAWLNZ602AHVzb6ZWkto7rjI+lApgm4D6q6H5R8IPUTpC3IRcartN8oL8PjKPVHjCS40WNokqw5iF4vVCplIU6ym0m-KzUcigA)

More specifically, why do the assignments to `bar` generate errors (especially the second one) but not the second assignment to `foo`.  I think it has something to do with type distribution in conditional types, but I can't really wrap my head around it.

Can someone explain what is going on here? (Note: This question is more about understanding what TS is doing here, rather than coming up with a workaround for the typing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a design limitation of TypeScript.  The compiler *defers* evaluation of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on an as-yet-unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, and thus it cannot really verify that anything is assignable to such types.  In your case, `Broken<T>` is a conditional type, and inside the implementation of `testBroken()`, the generic type parameter `T` on which it depends has not been specified (it only gets specified when you *call* `testBroken()`).  So `Broken<T>` is essentially opaque to the compiler and it cannot see that `value` is assignable to it, even if you could narrow `T` or `value` to a subtype of `string`.

Probably the canonical issue in GitHub surrounding this is [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  It suggests that the compiler should use control flow analysis to narrow `value` and thus possibly `T` to a subtype of `string`, and then use that to narrow `Broken<T>` to `T`.  If you want to see this happen you might want to go to that issue and give it a .  Until and unless this is supported, there are just workarounds.

Since the question is not about workarounds, I won't go into much detail, but briefly you can always use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to quell the warnings:

```
function testBrokenAssertion<T extends string | number>(value: T) {
    let bar: Broken<T>
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        bar = value as Broken<T>
    }
}
```

and you can even refactor these assertions into a helper function as shown in microsoft/TypeScript#33912:

```
function testBrokenHelper<T extends string | number>(value: T) {
  let bar: Broken<T>
  bar = conditionalProducingIf(value, isString, () => value, () => null) // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgTgewNYQHYB4AqUIA9hoAmAzlMcHAJaoDmUAPlKgK4C2ARhHAHxQC8UbHgKoSZCtToB+QVABcTZgBslAKFVKIwKADMECBfGRp05KrW6rCEAMZKAhnGibtAN3tLmEBWcmq9CPxQ7p4Q6tZ2js5awR5eAEw+ErQMihxcqgD0mVDAABaUpFyIcFCs9iikxGjVuYGs3rGh8VA2CMqEUJxQ9mmccP76QSEJqpQ6UAAUoJAIEyMQLXzLUABEvrSrAJRQAN6qUIdQ2T2iUJTa5ZVkNdDA9XcFpADuCHBIxAA0Xbb2zLWoBDPKDPaBIQHA-IQEA9JxdBD5cTmGjEA5HALDOKLVQAX3UOmYqBswEoCFQuQg5CMKAwQnwRCqyTojBY6R4kwWCkwO32RygLi6jkMiBpWEsfPYjkxoWOOWKbwAhGjDidlecJtNwBA5k0vPwVusmds9mq+ScAOp5GGFXJPU44OAlGTjNaSuCrc6kVCORCgzr3JGSKCEMkAcm0oKg4KBtvs2mpJkw4r5RxONo8xEChuRqykpqObulXjVeLx-kJxNJ5IIVJFaAAgsRqnASWSsDh6aJGcjUqz+twOViuTy1QK3cLjLTk4cXZrZvMsfqBNnJMbeSnDoWBAseqQE1OS7j1BaqAQALRkmzQPIQJSQAYEomt8ltUQXKseAAKiEIzBskgASR0dAABkIB0YAANQb4ACVKBoPJIOgqAwIggB5ZhgFg+DEIwrCoHrOA6GEBkUPApDUjghCkIHNVHBoBRCJoT41VfQgFEmeiFFQijGCoxCoJ2PheHoz0yIgqCWL5MAfz-CAeLwjiuPEpChN4BTMKko4ZIQX8r344BFKmZSDME-heAMvCtjkNUmI7EQxB4qCoBkDTtAUSzMJNPkZmgNCAGkgjskiuxU5zXPIvD5CgTzgAAbjVWc2M4oithHDdDicYBmDgckdL0+TIswlKaB2exSAChK+RxHAlFqdcNyynK8tk-ScMM4rRPKmL2rM7rKsPMsTwuCALyJa9b3vcsnyrT0AGUmRKhR7FQEBrNhOgbQ2OgGqgJrctyLUdVE5Zl221YErLR9KzJCla0nAAJSauHbEKxG23s2H7QdQmHbyjjHIVYDrA8JSlAQ2PfMkv1awCdB+rxvkKBbkW+SY1N1CA0YxlgVB2E5kHsEAj3UIA)

Comment: this was a really helpful answer.  thank you.  so basically, if you pass a generic to a conditional type the only thing you can then assign to that generic-conditional-type is that exact generic-conditional-type. so if your code has arrived at a narrower type you have to widen by assertion (whether explicitly or through a helper function).