# Can Typescript infer keys of a generic type inside conditional blocks?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I've got a function that accepts a an enum value as `T` and a generic type `Data<T>` that chooses between two data types.

I hoped to be able to access properties of type `BarData` inside a conditional that should make `T` known. However, it still reads `data` as a union type.

The code works as expected but what do I have to change to get rid of the typescript errors?

```
enum DataType { Foo, Bar }
interface FooData { someKey: string }
interface BarData extends FooData { otherKey: string }

type Data<T extends DataType> = T extends DataType.Foo ? FooData : BarData

function func<T extends DataType>(type: T, data: Data<T>): void {
    const getter = <K extends keyof Data<T>>(key: K): Data<T>[K] => data[key]

    if (type === DataType.Bar) {
        data; // still inferred as Data<T>
        console.log(data.otherKey) // error Property 'otherKey' does not exist on type 'FooData | BarData'.
        console.log(getter('otherKey')) // error Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Data<T>'.
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN5QGID2BANFAEJwBOUAvgLABQAliAsJQGZwDGWhB8JDigBnAhGABpYKgBcohJRYBzWoxZtOPLBUqC4UYAA82IACYj8RfcIIIAFu2lyFSkKvoNGCDFn0AeZEMTUAtYRBRfAD4oAF4oIONTMP00TAA6figAfisBCKh5XX1GRg4wEG4EJgIQKHLKwODky1TogAofTHlkUjMI+QDkKIBKeQA3AiYzHEYoeahuWpEEKGVgBE04qH9JZtDLAGsZAg5wpECoqPbjl0kx87hLgG1JAF04mP6kZ9u30oYCygTDOnV8cVi8TaGV0I1mgKBC2+cAA3FAAPTohRMAA2OOBIA47EowBmcFaEUuc0R8yWIDEOOA6RxBGU7WR6TsjkozjhmMMlEoBGoAAUhZhKD4oAByLlOGTSqBmAjASwgOzBJgrKC1KBdLDS-g2AA+5Co+ml6WpNLpDKZLLZ6027Hasoc8tQ0pGfKxxOFUAAgpRlJBQKtTnrwdKVm5lIqtVB1atySImMoQHAAEaMvUEKDoKhwCRbCP6mW3CNDKKW61qBg0IA)

Comment: Consider [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: I don't think generics will ever resolve inside the function implementation

Comment: What is it you actually want `func` to do? With more specifics, we can be more specifically helpful. :-) But as @captain-yossarian said, you're probably going to need/want typeguards.

Comment: I think this is basically the same question, with a helpful answer by @jcalz -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142672/conditional-type-that-narrows-a-union

In other words, the issue is that TS won't evaluate generics until instantiation, even though it appears knowable in this case because of your `if` statement.  Since you "know" the correct type inside your if statement, an assertion is OK--or a typeguard if you want a little more guaranteed safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that invalid state is unrepresentable. You can use rest parameters instead of generic.

```js
enum DataType { Foo = 'Foo', Bar = 'Bar' }

interface FooData { someKey: string }

interface BarData extends FooData { otherKey: string }


type MapStructure = {
  [DataType.Foo]: FooData,
  [DataType.Bar]: BarData
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Tuple = {
  [Prop in keyof MapStructure]: [type: Prop, data: MapStructure[Prop]]
}

// ---- > BE AWARE THAT IT WORKS ONLY IN T.S. 4.6 < -----

function func(...params: Values<Tuple>): void {
  const [type, data] = params
  const getter = <Data, Key extends keyof Data>(val: Data, key: Key) => val[key]

  if (type === DataType.Bar) {
    const foo = type
    data; // BarData
    console.log(data.otherKey) // ok
    console.log(getter(data, 'otherKey')) // ok
    console.log(getter(data, 'someKey')) // ok

  }
}
```

[Playground](http://tsplay.dev/mx6qXw)

`MapStructure` - is used just for mapping keys with valid state.

`Values<Tuple>` - creates a union of allowed tuples.Since rest parameters is nothing more than a tuple, it works like a charm.

Regarding `getter`. You should either define it inside `if` condition or make it separate function. SO, feel free to move `getter` out of the scope of `func`.

If you want to stick with generics, like in your original example, you should make `type` and `data` a part of one datastracture and then use [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

```js
enum DataType { Foo, Bar }
interface FooData { someKey: string }
interface BarData extends FooData { otherKey: string }

type Data<T extends DataType> = T extends DataType.Foo ? FooData : BarData

const isBar = (obj: { type: DataType, data: Data<DataType> }): obj is { type: DataType.Bar, data: BarData } => {
    const { type, data } = obj;
    return type === DataType.Bar && 'other' in data
}

function func<T extends DataType>(obj: { type: T, data: Data<T> }): void {
    const getter = <K extends keyof Data<T>>(key: K): Data<T>[K] => obj.data[key]

    if (isBar(obj)) {
        obj.data // Data<T> & BarData
        console.log(obj.data.otherKey) // ok       
    }
}
```

But issue with `getter` still exists since it depend on uninfered `obj.data`. You either need to move out `getter` of `func` scope and provide extra argument for `data` or move `getter` inside `conditional statement` (not recommended).

However, you can switch to TypeScript nightly in TS playground and use object type for argument:

```js
enum DataType { Foo, Bar }
interface FooData { someKey: string }
interface BarData extends FooData { otherKey: string }

type Data = { type: DataType.Foo, data: FooData } | { type: DataType.Bar, data: BarData }


function func(obj: Data): void {
    const { type, data } = obj;
    const getter = <K extends keyof typeof data>(key: K): typeof data[K] => data[key]

    if (type === DataType.Bar) {
        data // BarData
        console.log(obj.data.otherKey) // ok       
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQeqAw)

`getter` still does not work in a way you expect, hence I recomment to move it out from `func`

Comment: Thanks. Your first solution seems to work only in the 4.6 nightly build as well. I'll be going with the generics + type predicates option. I'm glad this type check also works when passing arguments individually and building the object inside the function: https://tsplay.dev/wEGYvm

Comment: @DustInCompetent you are right, forgot to mention it