# Type is not assignable to type 2322

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Why is the following raising : `Type '(...args: T) => void' is not assignable to type 'Fn<T>'.(2322)` :

```js
type Fn<T extends unknown[]|unknown> = T extends unknown[] ? (...args: T)=>void : T

const func = <T extends unknown[]>()=>{
    // why does this error and how does one resolve it?
    // ideal Fn must handle cases outside of unknown[] including `any` and `unknown`
    const fn : Fn<T> = (...args: T)=> console.log(args)
    return fn
}

// some tests by me to try and understand what is going on:
type ValidFn1 = Fn<[value:number]>
type ValidFn2 = Fn<any>
type ValidFn3 = Fn<never>
type ValidFn4 = Fn<unknown>
type ValidFn5 = Fn<unknown[]>
type ValidFn6 = Fn<void>

const validFn1: ValidFn1 = (...args)=>console.log(args) // extends unknown[]
const validFn2: ValidFn2 = (...args:any)=>console.log(args) // any extends unknown[]
const validFn3: ValidFn3 = (...args:never)=>console.log(args) // never doesn't extend unknown[]
const validFn4: ValidFn4 = (...args:unknown)=>console.log(args) // unknown doesn't extend unknown[]
const validFn5: ValidFn5 = (...args:unknown[])=>console.log(args) // extends unknown[]
const validFn6: ValidFn6 = (...args:void)=>console.log(args) // void doesn't extend unknown[]
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-sOHgrD4dBAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what is going on here is a combination of the fact that (1) Typescript does not resolve conditional types inside functions until it is presented with a concrete instantiation (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142672/conditional-type-that-narrows-a-union)) and (2) function parameters are contravariant (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496072/difference-between-covariant-and-contravariant-positions-in-typescript)).

So, what you have here is basically TS seeing this line:

```js
    const fn : Fn<T> = (...args: T)=> console.log(args)
```

And:

- Resolving `Fn<T>` inside `func` to `Fn<unknown[]>` , i.e., `(...args: unknown[]) => void`,(because of point 1 above)
- Realizing that `T` on the right side could be something narrower than `unknown[]` (e.g., `number[]`).

So it then thinks, well, that might not work because, that could be saying, for example:

```
   const fn:(args:unknown[])=>void = (args:number[])=>console.log(args)
```

And that is an error because args is contravariant (see point 2 above).

How do you fix it?  I think the easiest way to resolve issues under the point 1 category is with an explicit return type on the function and then just an assertion inside the function itsel, e.g.:

```js
const func = <T extends unknown[]>():Fn<T>=>{
    const fn = (...args: T)=> console.log(args)
    return fn as Fn<T>
}
```