# How to resolve Intersection and Union doesn't match in ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function that will create a different class by passing different args ,

but I am getting an error in the code below；

It looks like even though I specify the generic, typescript can't understand it

```js
type ClassAOptions = {
  fooA: string;
  barA: string;
};
class ClassA {
  constructor(options: ClassAOptions) {}

  static new(options: ClassAOptions): ClassA {
    return new ClassA(options);
  }
}

type ClassBOptions = {
  fooB: boolean;
  barB: boolean;
};
class ClassB {
  constructor(options: ClassBOptions) {}

  static new(options: ClassBOptions): ClassB {
    return new ClassB(options);
  }
}

const classList = {
  first: ClassA,
  second: ClassB,
};

function createClass<K extends keyof typeof classList>(
  className: K,
  args: ConstructorParameters<typeof classList[K]>[0]
) {
  //  type error
  //  Argument of type 'ClassAOptions | ClassBOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClassAOptions & ClassBOptions'.
  return new classList[className](->args<-);
}

createClass("first", { fooA: "false", barA: "false" });
createClass("second", { fooB: false, barB: false });
```

this type error is make me crazy, does anyone know why typescript will show an error here,

I can't find my answer on google at all;

Or let me know the key point of this type err, I can google it then

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that Typescript will not resolve `K` until you actually pass in a value to `createClass`.  In other words, it will not conditionally resolve `K` inside the generic function `createClass`, even though it is resolvable when `createClass` is called.

For more on this issue, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142672/conditional-type-that-narrows-a-union).

You can nevertheless achieve what you want via an explicit return type (return types are resolved when the function is actually called) and an internal assertion.

```js
function createClass<K extends keyof typeof classList>(
  className: K,
  args: ConstructorParameters<typeof classList[K]>[0]
): InstanceType<typeof classList[K]> {
  return new classList[className](args) as InstanceType<typeof classList[K]>;
}
```